# Unity3D v5.0 Pong/Breakout: Bounce balls accurately off of each other

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, bounce

I'm working on a kind of break-out clone 3d thingy type game. This is what I have for my Arena so far:

[image]

The Arena is:

- Arena

  - Walls: 6 Cubes. Mesh Colliders. Front wall is "transparent".
  - Balls: n Balls. Rigidbodies. Bounce around, breaking out of stuff
  - Paddle: A cube or a circular shaped item that deflects based on where it's hit (To be fleshed out)
  - Bricks: Square thingies that disappear when hit (To be fleshed out)

One of two issues I'm trying to solve at the moment is... as the balls bounce around, I can get them to bounce off the walls and the paddle (I need to get a good "change direction based on where it hits on the paddle" part in there, but the basics are there)...

But I can't seem to get them to bounce off of each other... Sphere Collider, SuperBouncyMaterial and Rigidbody... I'm not sure what exactly to put into the OnCollisionEnter.

How do you "accurately" bounce two balls off each other and get good resultant directions?

[Full Code](https://bitbucket.org/wernercd/unity.breakout/) at BitBucket, and the [BallScript](https://bitbucket.org/wernercd/unity.breakout/src/master/Assets/Prefabs/Balls/BallScript.cs) hidden therein.

Comment: What do you use to move them and are the rigidbodies kinetic?

Comment: Please, describe the problem in more detail. What happens when they collide, exactly? Do they go through each other?

Comment: @MaxYankov Balls are Mesh Colliders with RigidBodies. Walls are Mesh Colliders. Right now I use OnTriggerEnter to bounce them off of the walls - only have that code so far, since I'm not sure exactly how to get the balls to ricochet off each other. Bouncing off the walls makes the `inDirection` a simple left/right/up/etc... but that's not exactly how balls should bounce with regards to each other. I'll post some code tonight after work... maybe even pretty up the repository and link it.

Comment: Why are you putting information about your question in the comments? Please put it in the question.